# Should I use GAE + Lift for my Scala based webapp?

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, lift

Such questions have been asked before - but all of the answers are outdated now.

I am looking forward to work on a Scala based webapp. I understand this question can be split into two, but I am posting them as one because they rely on same context, there being a dependency on the hosting platform and frameworks used.

I have read multiple (awesome) debates on Play! and Lift, but cannot find a good comparison between Play! 2.1 and Lift. How do I decide which one is better for my scenario (a social network website) ?

Similarly, this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/JLNvFX-OptI) has some very good arguments as to which platform to use for if I go with Lift, but it's from 2010 and seems outdated. The recommended provider (stax.net) is dead (or I guess it's merged with cloudbees.com). I am personally inclined towards GAE, as they are quick to start with, but unsure if the issues still prevail :

1. Support for actors (I am not sure if Akka helps us solve this problem)
2. Requests for a given session being served by different JVMs without notice to running app
3. Quoting David Pollak (lead author of Lift) :

> GAE is slow and non-scalable, despite Google's claims (everyone I've
>   spoken with that have tried to scale GAE apps have failed and gone
>   elsewhere). GAE locks you into a tremendously suboptimal storage
>   mechanism. GAE is free, but so is Stax and there are many inexpensive
>   options including SliceHost.  Next up, you've got Amazon EC2 and
>   RackSpace. So, I haven't found a good reason for anyone to use GAE. 
>   And if there's no good reason to use GAE, devoting a pile of resources
>   to code around the GAE JVM incompatibilities (e.g., no new threads)
>   seems like a waste.

Another issue if I go with GAE is **lack of Play! 2.1 support**. I still don't see a module for that. Another issue is **difficulty to migrate** to other databases (although I hear migrating to MongoDB should be relatively easier) in the future. Worst case would be to move out of GAE and use AppScale.

Comment: I like the questions and agree that there have been many discussions about it, there doesn't seem to ever actually be a subjective comparison of the two web frameworks.

Many comments always seem to be in the vain of;
"I tried XXX for five minutes, once upon a time - didn't like it - so I used YYY instead. YYY is awesome... Choose XXX at your peril. YYY for the win."

I am currently learning Play myself and quite like it. But I have never given Lift anything more than a cursory glance - so can't help much with actually answering your question.

I would love to read a subjective review of the 2

Comment: Re GAE, the question really is, why would you want GAE? If you want a free/metered Java web server, there are many many other options today. If you want some GAE-specific feature, then you've already decided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I use [Lift](http://liftweb.net/), [Cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com/), and [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/welcome/) as my first choice for most of my projects.  I tried several cloud hosting services to no avail (Heroku and RedHat in particular.  I don't think I tried GAE due to the post from David Pollak that you have already referenced).  To use cloudbees, you just need an [sbt plugin](https://github.com/timperrett/sbt-cloudbees-plugin).  Then it is as easy as running the `cloudbees-deploy` target.  Within a minute, your code is up and running.  I was floored by how easy it was.  I went with Mongo primarily because of this excellent [g8 template](https://github.com/eltimn/lift-mongo.g8) (note, there is now an [SQL equivalent](https://github.com/tuhlmann/lift-bootstrap.g8))

Another thing I really like about Cloudbees and MongoLab is they both have free services.  It's great for me because I only work on these projects in my free time, so I don't want to spend any money while my ideas are half-baked.

As for Lift, I can't compare it much to Play.  I downloaded/installed play and was immediately turned off by how MVC it is.  I felt that the view-first approach, albeit foreign to me, seemed to be a much more intuitive and powerful way to build web applications.  I love how Lift doesn't obscure from me the fact that I am indeed developing a web application.  I often feel that MVC frameworks try to keep all of the HTML/CSS/JS etc at an arms-length.

Comment: Lift doesn't seem to have any reusable modules (like authentication, etc mentioned here : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Modules). Plus, the rate of development, though good, seems slower than Play!. Am I right ? I also wonder if I would ever want to expose a backend API (say for mobile apps), is there an easy way with Lift (I don't even know if Play helps) - like GAE offers a "Backend API" very quick to develop.

Comment: @Raj, one of Lift's weaknesses is its documentation. Because of that, it is possible you could walk away with the impression that features are not available or that something is more difficult than it actually is. Lift has an incredibly active community which hangs out on its mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb. While I can't speak about the relative rate of development, both are very actively maintained.  There is a list of user contributed modules: https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Modules, and other user contributions are often discussed on the list.

Comment: As for API development, Lift offers a very easy way of implementing a backend API via the use of its `RestHelper`: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-11.html and http://simply.liftweb.net/index-5.4.html. I've used it heavily and find it pretty easy, though your mileage may vary. One common usage scenario is to use Lift with a front end library like AngularJS, which will make heavy use of REST. In Lift 3, there are going to be many new features around that scenario (in addition to other development) - including streaming promises: http://blog.goodstuff.im/roundtrip_promises.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. I was a bit inclined towards Play! because of Java support (in case I needed additional team members who didn't know Scala); but Lift helped me start off better. Can you please share your experiences to this follow-up question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343286/network-latency-with-using-different-paas-solutions ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite open so I will share my experience and opinion regarding Scala web app development as it might help you with your decision.

I built my first scala web application using Scalatra and Scalate using Jetty as the server. The app is hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance and I've had no problems with this... it's been running since the end of 2011 with only one small blip that took 10 mins to resolve. I found it a good experience for learning to use Scala in web applications.

http://www.scalatra.org/

Typesafe (http://typesafe.com) appear to have opted for the Play Framework and so for my next scala based web app I am likely to go for Play. A book I have been reading on the Play Framework is "Play for Scala". It has just been published this month (Oct 2013).

http://www.manning.com/hilton/

My impression is that Lift was the go-to framework in the past but that this has shifted to the Play Framework.

Comment: It is my understanding that Lift passed on working with Typesafe instead of Typesafe opting for Play. See an explanation here: http://www.quora.com/Lift-web-framework/Why-did-Typesafe-select-Play-for-their-stack-instead-of-Lift/answer/David-Pollak I wouldn't say Play is the go-to, but definitely seems to be the path of least resistance coming from the Java/MVC world. Lift requires a better understanding of Scala and getting your head around a view first architecture, but once you do I think it has many strengths compared to other platforms, however the best choice will always be case specific.